# jQuery slideUp element A if visible then slideDown element B

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML form:-

```
<form id="subform">
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Go!"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <select id="optlist">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>
```

And the following jQuery snippet:-

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    // if address select list is visible slide it up and then slide down new <p> tag
    if ($('#optlist').is(":visible")) {
        $('form > p:nth-child(2)').slideUp('slow', function () {
            $('<p id="noresults">No results found</p>').insertAfter('form > p:nth-child(2)').hide().slideDown("slow");
        });
    }
    // else if select list is not visible just slide down the new <p> tag
    else {
        $('<p id="noresults">No results found</p>').insertAfter('form > p:nth-child(2)').hide().slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

What I want to do is, if `#optlist` is currently visible `slideUp()` THEN `slideDown()` a new `<p>` tag, otherwise just `slideDown()` a new `<p>` tag (if the `#optlist` is currently hidden).

This works fine above, although it's a bit clunky, for example I have to repeat the insertion of the new `<p>` in both the `if` and the `else` statement.

Also in addition to this, there is a small bug, if the `#noresults <p>` tag already exists it will currently add another one, how could i get it to flash the current `#noresults` if it already exists ?

I could check to see if it exists using `if ( $("#noresults").length ) {};` but i would also need to repeat this (in the `if` and `else`).

I could put the checking and creation of the new `<p>` in a function and make a call to it.

Is there a better way of structuring the current code ?

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/general_exception/zjUXV/6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that since the desired behavior is always to hide the #optlist and show the #noresults div.  That you could do something like this:

The HTML:

```
<form id="subform">
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Go!"/>
    </p>
    <p id="optlist_container">
        <select id="optlist">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p id="noresults" style="display: none;">No results found</p>
</form>
```

And for jQuery:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#optlist_container').slideUp('slow', function() {
        $('#noresults').slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

I don't see any reason to check for the visibility of #optlist if you are always going to be hiding it anyways. And you can easily just have the #noresults element in place to begin with so you have no reason to continue to append it.

Answer (score 1):

You never have to repeat code. You can always move repeated code to a function.

For example, making the smallest change to your code to avoid the repetition:

```
function noResults() {
    $('<p id="noresults">No results found</p>')
        .insertAfter('form > p:nth-child(2)')
        .hide()
        .slideDown("slow");
}

$("#btn").click(function() {
    // if address select list is visible slide it up and then slide down new <p> tag
    if ($('#optlist').is(":visible")) {
        $('form > p:nth-child(2)').slideUp('slow', noResults);
    }
    // else if select list is not visible just slide down the new <p> tag
    else {
        noResults();
    }
});
```

I also took the long jQuery chain in the repeated code and reformatted it for readability. Removing the repetition makes that more feasible.